# Global minimum of a many-variables function on a specified domain

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization

My target is to compute the *global* minimum of the real function $f$.
$$
 f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4): D\subset \mathbb{R}^4\quad \to \quad \mathbb{R}
$$
Of course the minimum can either be a stationary point of $f$, i.e. a point where $\nabla f=(0,0,0,0)$ or a point that belongs to the domain's frontier. I can easily compute the stationary points of $f$ and check if they are minima, maxima etc, but I am still trying to figure how to exaustively explore the frontier of the domain. 
The domain $D$ is such that:
$$
 0\le x_1 \le 1 \quad \wedge \quad 0 \le x_2 \le 1 \quad \wedge \quad x_2 \le 1-x_1 
$$ 
$$
 0\le x_3 \le 1 \quad \wedge \quad 0\le x_4 \le 1 \quad \wedge \quad x_4 \le 1-x_3 
$$ 
So, if I am correct, the domain of $f$ is the direct product of 2 triangular regions. Any idea about how to find the global minimum of $f$ in its domain, i.e. about how to explore the domain's frontier of $f$?

Comment: Maybe analyzing $f(\varphi(u,v))$, where $\varphi(u,v)$ is the parametrization of your frontier? ($\varphi(u,v) = ( u, 1-u,v,1-v)$ with $\varphi:[0,1]x[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I fear that the parametrization $\varphi(u,v)$ that you've kindly suggested does not fit my problem. In fact $(u,1-u)$ is just the parametrization of the hypotenuse, not of the complete frontier, which actually is a triangle. Maybe should I analyze different cases, corresponding to the different choices of the piece of frontier under analysis?

Comment: what do we know about $f$, is it convex?

Comment: No, in general it is not convex.

Comment: @AndreaPaco you're right, I rushed with my answer. Maybe analysing the 9 cases of each piece easy to parametrize, as you said, should do the trick. That's inuitively what comes to my mind.

Comment: @Max, no problem, it happens. Why do you talk about $9=3\times 3$ cases too? From an intuitive point of view, I'm not sure if the right way to proceed is to consider $9=3 \times 3$ cases, (meaning that you are considering *combined* constraints) or $6=3+3$ cases (meaning that you're considering *separately* each single constraint). What is your opinion?

Comment: @AndreaPaco Ok, so trying to show you why 6 cases were wrong, I found it's right. Only you have to be careful. Tell you why I saw this, with an example. Take in $\mathbb{R}^3$  $ [0,1]\times \{ 0\le x_2 \le 1 \quad \wedge \quad 0 \le x_3 \le 1 \quad \wedge \quad x_3 \le 1-x_2 \}$. Then you have a "triangle x interval" , which has 5 pieces as its frontier. The triangle has 3 pieces of frontier seen separately (each side), and the inteval has 2 (0 and 1).

Comment: The pieces are of the form: "take (a piece of) the frontier of the triangle and take product with the whole interval" and " take (a piece of ) the frontier of the interval and take product with the triangle". That is to say: $$ side_1 \times [0,1] $$ $$ side_2 \times [0,1] $$ $$ side_3 \times \[0,1] $$ $$ triangle \times \{0\} $$ $$ triangle \times \{1\} $$

Comment: The same happens with the cube $[0,1]\times [0,1]\times [0,1]$, which has also 6 pieces of frontier (namely, its faces) and each one can be constructed taking separately each piece of the frontier of each object in the product (in this case all three objects are the interval $[0,1]$ and the pieces of their frontier are $\{0\} $ and $\{1\}$ ) and take product with the rest.

Comment: What is your objective function ?  If you can rewrite your objective function in the form $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = g(x_1,x_2)  +  h(x_3,x_4) $  for some functions $g$ and $h$   then your problem is separable, and you can solve it as easy as slice of a Cake

Comment: Ehm, I wish it was separable, but it is not.